# How to custom mapping Firebase Datasnapshot with custom object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a key and value that key is reserved-word in java.

```
{
  class:"1/1"
}
```

How can I map the datasnapshot with custom class

```
CustomClass customClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomClass.class);
```

CustomClass.java

```
public class CustomClass{
  private String class //can not use class or Class
}
```

Comment: thanks @adjuremods for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`@PropertyName`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName), which marks a field to be renamed when serialized.

```
public class Foo {

    @PropertyName("class")
    private String clazz;

    public String getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(String clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nathanielC . but now I have a new problem _no setter found for class_ (Not found **setClazz** method) and I solve it by change `private String clazz` -> `public String clazz`